# Don't show ads for Android API 8 or lower

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Users with Android version 2.2 (API 8) don't seem to appreciate the advertisements that are in my Android application. I would like to disable ads for this Android version or lower. Is there some kind of if/else statement that can prevent the showAdsBanner() and showAdsInterstitial() functions from being loaded? This way the ads won't be loaded and shown to my users.

```
public class App extends DroidGap implements AdListener
{
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private AdView adView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());

        showAdsBanner();
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                showAdsInterstitial();
            }
        }, 2500);
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to Java and I can't seem to find a working solution. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8) {
        showAdsBanner();
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                showAdsInterstitial();
            }
        }, 2500);
    }
```